# $POST method firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `$POST` method in jQuery which sends id as data to my PHP file and deletes that row from the database using that id. My problem is that every time click the delete button the POST method is called multiple times.

here is the code.

```
$(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '.member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .single-row .action-column .action-holder .delete-image', function() {

  var div_id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
  //$(".dash-wrapper .display-class .member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .modal .modal-content")
  $(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '#yes1', function() {
    $.post("delete.php", {
      id1: div_id
    }, function(data) {
      if (data == 1) {
        $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        ajaxcall3();
      } else {

      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: yknow, you don't need an else if there is going to be nothing in it. Not gonna solve your problem, it's just to save lines

Comment: Please show us *every* block that the `$(".dash-wrapper .display-class")` will select.

Comment: Post HTML here.

Comment: could you include the function `ajaxcall3();`

Comment: @Wndrr $(".dash-wrapper .display-class") is the wrapper and anything inside that changes with ajax call. So basically I am calling the post method in a dynamic HTML which changes on my dashboard button click

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example ? Maybe copy/paste the ajax-included HTML that causes the problem ? `.one()` might do the job, but it feels like a hack here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* that every time you click on a delete image your AJAX call is made 1 more time. It's because you bind a new event handler on every click on the delete image, to fix it either bind the `click` one time before the click on `delete-image` and use a global variable to have the `id` or unbind the click handler every time you reassign it as following :

```
$(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '.member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .single-row .action-column .action-holder .delete-image', function() {

  var div_id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
  $(".dash-wrapper .display-class").off('click', '#yes1');
  $(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '#yes1', function() {
    $.post("delete.php", {
      id1: div_id
    }, function(data) {
      if (data == 1) {
        $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        ajaxcall3();
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: OMG bro this fixed the problem! Marking this as the answer

Answer (score 3):

Try with [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

The `.one()` method is identical to `.on()`, except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation.

Example:

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

Comment: Nice **one** ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '.member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .single-row .action-column .action-holder .delete-image', function(){


});


//$(".dash-wrapper .display-class .member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .modal .modal-content")
$(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '#yes1', function(e){

var div_id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
  $.post("delete.php", {
      id1: div_id
    }, function(data){
      if(data==1){
        $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        ajaxcall3();
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  )
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Add that line before the close of your click function and add element e 
this will stop the propagation of your click even

Comment: Why ? please add an explanation. What makes you believe this will fix his problem and what led you to believe so ? We don't even know what type element his code is called on

Comment: the e.prevent default is an additional line of code to be added inside the click event. It doest not mean that i reconstruct your previous code.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, you've got two on click's here. Might that be the issue?

Could there possibly be some sort of loop created in ajaxcall3()?

You're not one of those people that click twice every time they just need to click once, are you?

Do you have a problem with your mouse drivers, or your mouse itself?

Without all the code, I'm just going to assume it's something silly, so try removing the extra on click first.

```
$(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '.member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .single-row .action-column .action-holder .delete-image', function(){

    var div_id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: "id1="+div_id,
        dataType: "text",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == '1') {
                $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
                $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                ajaxcall3();
            }
        }
    });
})
```

If that doesn't cut it, try unbinding the click event before POSTing

```
$(".dash-wrapper .display-class").on('click', '.member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .single-row .action-column .action-holder .delete-image', function(){

    var div_id = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: "id1="+div_id,
        dataType: "text",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .single-row .action-column .action-holder .delete-image').unbind('click');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == '1') {
                $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
                $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                ajaxcall3();
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.member-list-div .all-member-box .member-content-shell .single-row .action-column .action-holder .delete-image').bind('click');
        }
    });
});
```

I did not test this, and I'm just making this up as I go. No guarantees it will work!

*EDIT*
Parenthesis problems.

Comment: I got the solution and i marked it as the right answer!
Thank you for your time :)